# Find string in textfile use re.match function in python

Tags: python

This is my code so far.  I can't find the problem with the re.match

```
import os
import re

folderpath = 'D:/Workspace'
typeOfFile = [".c", ".C", ".cpp", ".CPP"]

for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(folderpath):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(tuple(typeOfFile)):
            data= open(os.path.join(dirname, filename), "r").readlines()

            m= re.match(r'author*.[^:=]*[:=]*(.[^\n]+)', data, re.DOTALL)

            if m: 
                author = m.group(1)
            else:
                author = 'unknown'
            print "author is this case is:", author, "in file", filename
```

I want to search string author in textfile.

Comment: Use `search` instead of `match`

Comment: r'author*.[^:=]*[:=]*(.[^\n]+)' i think the problem here

Comment: What does the text you are trying to match look like? That regex is really strange... `r*.` - you really want to match any number of r's followed by a single character?

Comment: You aren't making to the regex. `if filename.endswith(tuple(typeOfFile))` is only true if the filename ends with ".c.C.cpp.CPP". Try something like `if os.path.splitext(filename)[1].lower() in ('.c', '.cpp')`.

Comment: @tdelaney: Why not?  `str.endswith()` [has been accepting tuples since Python 2.5](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith).

Comment: @TimPietzcker - geez, you're right. I thought it concatenated the strings but apparently not.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match):

> ```
> re.match(pattern, string, flags=0)
> ```
>
> If zero or more characters *at the beginning of `string`* match the regular expression `pattern`, return a
>   corresponding `MatchObject` instance.

Use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) instead.

Comment: The OP will also want `.read()` to get one large string to work with rather than `.readlines()` (I get a feeling an exception is being omitted from the question)

Comment: @JonClements - he's not making it into the if statement yet - the exception will be next!